# How do i display field values from a related objects in my lightning data table in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-datatable, lwc-wire-adapter

Hi im trying to display some parent object fields in my data table and for some reason the fields are not being displayed. I have tried flattening my json but still no luck. Looking for some help to please point me to what i might be missing.

HTML:

```
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:settings"  variant="brand" alternative-text="Settings"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:adduser"   variant="brand" alternative-text="Add user" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Add user"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:delete"    variant="brand" alternative-text="Delete"   class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Delete"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:save"      variant="brand" alternative-text="Save"     class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Save"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:bookmark"  variant="brand" alternative-text="Bookmark" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Bookmark"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:zoomin"    variant="brand" alternative-text="Zoom in"  class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Zoom in"></lightning-button-icon>
            <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:zoomout"   variant="brand" alternative-text="Zoom out" class="slds-m-left_xx-small" title="Zoom out"></lightning-button-icon>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div> 
</lightning-card>
```

My JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchDataHelper from './fetchDataHelper';
import getContactList from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getContactList';




const actions = [
    { label: 'Show details', name: 'show_details' },
    { label: 'Delete', name: 'delete' },
];

const columns = [
    { label: 'ID', fieldName: 'Id', type: 'Id' },
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: 'Email', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Birthdate', fieldName: 'Birthdate', type: 'date' },
    { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'AccountIndustry', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Annual Income', fieldName: 'Account_SDO_PA_Annual_Income__c', type: 'text' },
];

export default class DataTablePractice extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track columns = columns;

    @wire(getContactList) 
    wiredContacts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            let fixeddata = [];
            this.data.forEach((row) =>{
                let dataline = {};
                dataline.Id = row.Id;
                dataline.Name = row.Name;
                dataline.Email = row.Email;
                dataline.Birthdate = row.Birthdate;

                dataline.AccountIndustry = row.Account.Industry;
                dataline.Account_SDO_PA_Annual_Income__c = row.Account.SDO_PA_Annual_Income__c;

                fixeddata.push(dataline);
                console.log(fixeddata);
            })
            this.data = fixeddata;
            this.error = undefined;

        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.contacts = undefined;
        }
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return [
            SELECT Id, Name, Email, Account.SDO_PA_Annual_Income__c,Birthdate,Account.Industry 
            FROM Contact
            WHERE account.SDO_PA_Annual_Income__c != NULL
            WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
            LIMIT 10
        ];
    }
}
```

Any suggestions or help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for including code! Are you getting any errors or do you see anything in a console or debug log that you could include by [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/355193/edit) your question to add? Be sure to take the SFSE [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour), visit the [Help Center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help), answer questions and otherwise contribute to SFSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `wiredContacts` function you are looping over `this.data.forEach((row) =>{` But `this.data` is empty, you have not set it yet. I think you want to loop over the local `data` variable in your function (remove the **this**) `data.forEach((row) =>{`

Comment: Thank you! this solved it.